# WebView with Video chat (google.meets) support in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome

I am looking for a way to make use of video conference tools, such as google.meets or zoom inside an flutter app.

Currently I try to use google meets. First, I noticed that it is important to make sure desktop view is selected on the web view, otherwise the google meets invitation link will forward you to the app store to download the google meets app.
Second I noticed that it is important that chrome/safari browser is used that meets works.

At the moment I was not able to achieve this with webview_flutter or flutter_inappwebview (InAppWebView does not use chrome browser on my phone, however using ChromeSafariBrowser does open a new Window and I need it as Widget inside the flutter app).

Does anyone have some advice how I could achieve this? Any Plugin recommendations?

Comment: did you find the solution for WebView that works with meet?